# getTopLinkTemplate is null with Spring

Tags: java, spring, templates, toplink

I'm trying to use TopLink with Spring but I'm having a problem. I'm using it in a webservice (CXF).
When I use getTopLinkTemplate(), the resul is null.
Here is my applicationContext.xml :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@*************" />
    <property name="username" value="*****" />
    <property name="password" value="*****" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.toplink.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="toplink-sessions.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myProductDao" class="ToplinkExecPS.ExecPS">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="mySessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

My code is :

```
public class ExecPS extends TopLinkDaoSupport{

public Vector Exec(String test) 
{
    TopLinkTemplate t;
    t = getTopLinkTemplate();
    if (t == null)
        System.out.println("template is null");
}
```

}

So, when I execute this code, I have "template is null" in the console and a nullPointerException when I try to use the variable "t".

For information, the connection to the database with TopLink is successful.

> [TopLink - Infos] : 2012.05.23 03:45:22.113--ServerSession(4812898)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Session - connexion réussie

I have testing so many things and I'm still stuck. I hope you will help me.

[EDIT]

OK I'm really a noob. I just forget to get my bean before call the method...
If anyone get on this thread, there is the code:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"ToplinkContext.xml"} );
    ExecPS exec = (ExecPS)context.getBean("myProductDao");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this one but I would be suspicious of this line:

```
<property name="configLocation" value="toplink-sessions.xml" />
```

Unsure toplink-sessions.xml is on your classpath and try the following:

```
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:toplink-sessions.xml" />
```

Comment: I already had some trouble with this file, but spring specified me that was wrong ("This file is not on your classpath, blabla").